# How to add user #define to the GCC predefined macros?

Tags: gcc, toolchain

I'm building GCC cross-compiler from scratch. I need to add my own #define to the predefined macros. How to do it? I have not found any configure option for this purpose.

I expect that the command

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E -
```

lists my option:

```
#define __MY_OPTION__
```